# npm start suddenly stops working on react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I've been learning react for about two weeks, when suddenly npm start won't run. This is what I get instead:

```
sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! recipe-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the recipe-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Michelle/.npm/_logs/2020-07-29T14_35_20_988Z-debug.log
```

After a ton of googling I tried
`npm install -g npm@latest` but the permission was denied.

Deleted and reinstalled node several times, tried using Homebrew, etc, but nothing worked.

Edit: Found the solution!
Npm couldn't find react-scripts, so I had to change the scripts in `package.json` to
`"start": "node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"`.

Comment: Are you sure you're in the same directory as your package.json file when running the command? - npm looks to this for commands

Comment: What output do you get when just running `npm`

Comment: @MikeW added it in the post above

Comment: I'm seeing you're new to the StackOverflow community. I would suggest you to take knowledge of the content you can find in the Help Center. In particular this section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers in particular in order to avoid writing the solution in your own question.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as the most appropriate answer :) (even if it's yours)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install react-scripts

```
npm install react-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the logs you just sent indicates your computer doesn't know the command `react-scripts`.

It means you need to install it.

When you use the `-g` option with `npm install`, it means you want to install globally the package, setting the package accessible for every user on your computer. That's why you have a permission error. You can solve this by adding `sudo` before the command maybe or running it with a elevated user.

It's not mandatory to install the package globally.

I suppose your `package.json` file contains a script named `start` starting with `react-scripts`.

If you install the `react-scripts` package with `npm install react-scripts`, you'll find the binary under `node_modules/.bin/react-scripts`.

Then you can replace in your `start` script configuration `react-scripts` with `./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts`.

An example of a `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts [...]",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried installing the react scripts, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

running "npm install react-scripts" even if I had before, worked for me